# What if we found many points satisfying KKT conditions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have the following convex optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x} & \quad f(X)\\
s.t. &\quad \sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ij}X_{ij} -  \sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ji}X_{ji}= 0, \forall i\\
& \quad 0 \leq X_{ij} \leq 1, \forall i, j =1, 2, \cdots, n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Since we have infinite points satisfying $\sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ij}X_{ij} -  \sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ji}X_{ji}= 0$, then I got many points (cannot enumerate all points) satisfying KKT conditions.

Here for this problem, it satisfies Slater’s condition and thus we have strong duality.
So I am wondering if this case happens and then should I say all of these points are optimal???

---

Re-edit:
$f(X)$ is concave.

Actually, I can find one feasible solution from the linear system $\sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ij}X_{ij} -  \sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ji}X_{ji}= 0$ and it satisfies all of the KKT conditions.

I am just wondering if I can take this solution as the optimal one due to the strong duality. If that’s true, I do not need to verify other solutions from $\sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ij}X_{ij} -  \sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ji}X_{ji}= 0$.

Comment: Not all points satisfying $\sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ij}X_{ij} -  \sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ji}X_{ji}= 0$ satisfy the KKT conditions! Those will at the very least limit you to the corners of the feasible region. There is a large number of those, but there are finitely many.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for your reply. Yes, I just cannot verifies every solution from the linear constraints. But I can find one feasible solution satisfying all of the KKT conditions. So I am wondering if this solution is the optimal one and then I do not need to verify other solutions.

Comment: That's not what your question is asking. Can you edit your question to be more clear about what you want to know?

Comment: Sure, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Also, the KKT conditions are for *minimizing* a convex function, not for maximizing it...

Answer (score 1):

If you have found a point that satisfies the KKT conditions, then it is an optimal solution. It will be the unique optimal solution when $f$ is *strictly* concave; otherwise, it's possible that there are multiple equally good optimal solutions.

Some fine print about the properties we're using:

- We need to be looking at a convex program in order to draw this conclusion from the KKT conditions **in gradient form**. But if you have a point that satisfies the KKT conditions **in saddle point form**, you don't need convexity. Admittedly, verifying the KKT conditions in saddle point form is less practical.
- The Slater condition on convex programs isn't necessary for this direction. Its purpose is to rule out cases in which no point satisfies the KKT conditions, but a degenerate optimal solution exists. (So if the KKT conditions have no solution, you need something like the Slater condition to conclude that there is no optimal solution. But for a bounded convex program, that's impossible anyway.)